# Can anyone recommend a free Map API to use

Tags: api

Can anyone help me with a free Map API I could use for my website? I would like to use the users IP address and display nearby Ports.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kind if ports? Shipping ports? If Ethernet ports, you want a floorpan app, not mapping. If real mapping, use [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) as a front-end to Open Street Maps (and be aware of our sister site https://gis.stackexchange.com/. Btw, your question is ***far*** to broad. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 2):

[OpenLayers.com](https://openlayers.org/) - probably the best alternative to Google Maps. Key features: free, open source, solid documentation.
[Github repo](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers).

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Yes it’s shipping ports I would like to use the Map API for.

If I use OpenLayers which seems to be the best free API would I need to then access a database of port information such as name and location. Is this information free?

Answer (score 2):

On this web page you get a lot of previews of free web map services  that cover the globe. Some services are entirely free, some require registration and an API key but are still free up to a threshold.

http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/

You don't have to use Leaflet to use these web map services, it just so happens that someone from the Leaflet community has compiled all the provider endpoint URLs and created the nice preview page.

What matters is the URL given in the red font in the small text window.